# font wont work. I thought I had the CSS correct

Tags: font-face

I am trying to put a font on my web page. It is called whoa I got all the files and put fontface on my css but it does not display even when I show it locally. I have thehere is my CSS:

```
     @font-face
    {
    font-family:"Whoa!";
    src:url("whoa_.eot?")
    format("eot"), url("whoa_.woff")
    format("woff"), url("whoa_.ttf")
    format("truetype"), url("whoa_.svg#Whoa!")
    format("svg");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    }

    .container h1 {
    font-family: Whoa!;

    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "!" from font-family in your font-face declaration.

Also, in your .container h1 CSS, you should put the font family declaration in quotes.

EDIT: If you're accessing this font locally and not using a URL, you need to make sure you have this font installed properly on your hard drive.  When you call this font within your CSS, make sure the font name matches the file name in your fonts directory.